# How to get last created folder with RootDirInfo.GetDirectories().Where(filter)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have the bellow function that works greate but is there away to do that with filter ?

**I am looking for something like :**

```
RootDirInfo.GetDirectories().Where(x => x.CreationTime >= Max(x.CreationTime));
```

**My function :**

```
public static DirectoryInfo GetLastCreatedDir(string BasePath)
        {
            //string LastCreatedDirName = string.Empty;
            DateTime LastDate = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01);
            DirectoryInfo RootDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(BasePath);
            DirectoryInfo LastDirInfo = null;

            //Get last Created Owners Idx Folder (by date) 
            foreach (DirectoryInfo InnerDirInfo in RootDirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(InnerDirInfo.CreationTime, LastDate) > 0)
                {
                    LastDirInfo = InnerDirInfo;
                    LastDate = InnerDirInfo.CreationTime;
                    //LastCreatedDirName = InnerDirInfo.Name;
                }
            }
            return LastDirInfo;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like:

```
var mostRecentDirInfo = dirfo.GetDirectories().
                          OrderByDescending(d=>d.CreationTime).Take(1);
```

- sort collection of directories by descending based on CreationTime
- pick the first one in sorted collection

Comment: Note that `Take` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the most recent directory like this

```
DirectoryInfo mostRecentDir = RootDirInfo.GetDirectories()
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTime)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```